# iOS React Native Testflight EXC_CRASH(SIGABRT) only for the Apple Tester

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight

For some reasons our internal testers was able to run the app but somehow the apple beta tester says the app crashes as soon as the app launches. They provided me with this error

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  1

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18d80827c 0x18c9e29f8 0x101124b94 0x101121108 0x18d80f900 0x18d6f14d0 0x18d6f2104 0x101137f20 0x1011778b4 0x101177614 0x18d247a38 0x18d2487d4 0x18d1f1324 0x18d1f1e40 0x18d1fa4ac 0x18d428114 0x18d42acd4)

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018d3a50dc 0x18d382000 + 143580
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018d41e094 0x18d41c000 + 8340
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018d2feea8 0x18d2a4000 + 372392
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018c9cb788 0x18c9ca000 + 6024
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018c9cb934 0x18c9ca000 + 6452
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018c9e2e00 0x18c9dd000 + 24064
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018c9d7838 0x18c9ca000 + 55352
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018c9d78c4 0x18c9ca000 + 55492
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018d2487e8 0x18d1e8000 + 395240
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018d1f1324 0x18d1e8000 + 37668
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018d1f1e40 0x18d1e8000 + 40512
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018d1fa4ac 0x18d1e8000 + 74924
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018d428114 0x18d41c000 + 49428
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018d42acd4 0x18d41c000 + 60628
```

im really not sure why the apple developer is experiencing crashes while the rest of the team was able to run the app normally through the testflight